# MIPS ignoring "Beq" statement

Tags: assembly, mips

So, i have this question where i have to translate the C code:

```
if (A == 2 || B == 3 && C != 4)
printf(“TRUE”);
else
printf(“FALSE”);
```

into MIPS assembly.
I have managed to store the tree integers in difirent registrators but when i make the comparison with "beq" i'm getting something wrong, it's always printing "true" regardless my inputs, and when i debug, the problem is in the first "beq" who skips my conditions to print "true" always and i don't know why, any help will be appreciable.
that's my code:

```
.data
varA:   .word   2
A:  .asciiz "A: "
B:  .asciiz "B: "
C:  .asciiz "C: "
outputTrue:   .asciiz     "\nTrue"
outputFalse:   .asciiz     "\nFalse"

.text

addi $t0, $zero, 2
addi $t1, $zero, 3
addi $t2, $zero, 4

.globl main

main:
li  $v0, 4
la  $a0, A
syscall

li  $v0, 5
syscall

move    $t3, $v0

li  $v0, 4
la  $a0, B
syscall

li  $v0, 5
syscall

move    $t4, $v0

li  $v0, 4
la  $a0, C
syscall

li  $v0, 5
syscall

move    $t5, $v0
syscall

#t3 = A, $t0 2
#t4 = B, $t1 3
#t5 = C, $t2 4

beq $t3, $t0, outputT
beq $t4, $t1, checkT

outputT:
li $v0, 4
la $a0, outputTrue
syscall
j   EXIT

outputF:
li $v0, 4
la $a0, outputFalse
syscall
j   EXIT

checkT:

beq $t5, $t2, outputF
beq $t4, $t1, outputT

EXIT:
li  $v0, 10
syscall
```

I'm new with stackoverflow and MIPS :(

Comment: Generally a bad idea to mix `$8` register numbers with `$t0` register names.  For example, **`$8` is the same register as `$t0`**.  https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MIPS_Assembly/Register_File.  Single-step your code with a debugger and watch register values.

Comment: Do not mix numeric and symbolic registers because it's hard to follow. `$8` is for example `$t0` so the `move    $8, $v0` already destroys the value you set earlier with `addi $t0, $zero, 2`

Comment: thanks for the advices, but looks like thats not the problem, i still got "true" as return regardless of my input

Comment: It was definitely *a* problem, possibly not the only problem.  After editing the code in your question (and saving before your re-assemble / re-run), what do you see with a debugger when single-stepping?  When you reach `beq $t3, $t0, outputT`, do you see `$t0` and `$t3` both holding `2` if you input something else?  Your question still claims that's what happens when you single-step.

Comment: Note that if neither of the two `beq` jump, then you fall through into `outputT`.

Comment: No,  when i debugg single-steping, the registrer $t0 always holds "2" and $t3 always holds "input n", regardless, the output is always "True".
Looks like he is jumping both "beq" statements and printing true, any thoughts why?